# @me called by anonymous error when using google plus api inside a gwt project

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-plus

I'm using the [google api javascript client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted) to get information about the user profile inside a gwt project hosted in google app engine.

In localhost, the data is being retrieved correctly. I get a json with the google plus profile. When I deploy to appengine, the response is 401, "@me called by anonymous".

Here is my Code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    auth();
});

var API_KEY = "***************************************";
var CLIENT_ID = "************.apps.googleusercontent.com";

var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

function auth() {
        var config = {
                'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
                'scope' : scopes,
                'key' : API_KEY,
        };
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
                        api.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
                        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
                            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                                    'userId' : 'me',
                            });
                            request.execute(function(resp) {
                                    console.log(resp);
                            });
                        });
        });
}

</script>
```

What i tried:

- call to api.client.setApiKey at the begining.
- create a new google api access with the google api console

---

update:

This is the complete response error message:

```
{
  "error": {
   "code": 401,
   "message": "me called by anonymous",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "authError",
     "message": "me called by anonymous",
     "locationType": "header",
     "location": "Authorization"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
}
```

There are other messages that may be related:

This is one of them:

```
Skipping duplicate osapi method definition chili.people.list on transport googleapis; others may exist, but suppressing warnings cb=gapi.loaded1 (línea 119)
Skipping duplicate osapi method definition pos.plusones.list on transport googleapis; others may exist, but suppressing warnings cb=gapi.loaded1 (línea 119)
Skipping duplicate osapi method definition chili.activities.list on transport googleapis; others may exist, but suppressing warnings cb=gapi.loaded1 (línea 119)
Skipping duplicate osapi method definition googleapis.newHttpRequest on transport googleapis; others may exist, but suppressing warnings
```

this is the other:

```
Invalid auth token. 1025***** vs 140186****
```

Comment: What does the response body for that HTTP 400 look like? This can shed some light on the root cause. It often contains an error message. Often times it's something simple like the JavaScript origin in the API console not matching up.

Also, here's a working JavaScript sample that does something very similar to what you're attempting: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html

Comment: @jenny-murphy Thanks for the sample. I've just added the response error message

Comment: @jenny-murphy I've tried the sample and I've got the same error.

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like something is up with your API key. Can you make sure that the Google+ API switch is toggled to 'on' on the services list on the API console? If that does not do the trick can you share either the full source code or a link to this running somewhere?

Comment: @jenny-murphy The google plus api is toggled on on the services list of the api console. I will try to post the code... I will have to get permission from my boss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally resolve the issue with the following settings or steps:

1) In the google apis console, I left the *Redirect URIs* section empty and completed the *JavaScript origins* section with the url of my site, repeating it with the **https** protocol:

```
JavaScript origins:
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

I put the script that loads the api before the end body tag:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```

This script comes inside the body, before the api script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var API_KEY = "***************************************";
var CLIENT_ID = "************.apps.googleusercontent.com";

var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

function auth() {
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1000);

    function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id : CLIENT_ID,
            scope : scopes,
            immediate : false
        }, handleAuthResult);
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult) {
            makeApiCall();
        } else {
            checkAuth();
        }
    }

    function makeApiCall() {
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                'userId' : 'me'
            });
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                $("#image").attr("src", resp.image.url);
            });
        });
    }

}
</script>
```

Then I call the function auth() when the user clicks to see his picture.